# E-reader that syncs progress across Linux and Android?

Tags: android, linux, sync

I've found some e-readers that *support* Linux and Android such as FBReader, but are there any that can *sync* progress across the two?

Comment: I would find it hard to imagine that any two reading systems would be capable of sharing syncs. That sounds like something which is done within  the same app across platforms. There would need to be a separate framework independent of apps to do this, and I don't see this happening anytime soon (linux or no linux).

Answer (score 1):

There's a way, but it's kinda tricky.

There's a bunch of android apps which sync the progress across the devices (like [Moon+ Reader](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.flyersoft.moonreader)). So, if you can set up an Android emulator on your Linux machine, that should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

FBReader supports this feature. They call it "book network".

It synchronizes reading progress and ebook files via Google Drive.

1. On the Android device, go to Settings -> Synchronization and enable it.
2. On Linux, install fresh FBReader (version 2.0.3 from `sudo snap install fbreader` worked for me but not the old one from the apt repo). Press the cloud icon, and everything seems to work afterwards.

Official tutorials: https://books.fbreader.org/tutorials.html.

FBReader is also available for iOS, MacOS, and Windows. While it was previously open source, now the snap packages a proprietary new version.